# Alias/Override helpers loaded using ActiveSupport.on_load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

Devise provide several helper methods such as `current_user`. It [uses ActiveSupport's `on_load`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L64) to lazily load these helpers into the controllers.

However this means that when I first starts Rails, my attempt to alias these helper methods will not work correctly. For example:

```
# in my ApplicationController
alias_method :devise_current_user, :current_user
def current_user
  user = devise_current_user
  if !user && !devise_controller?
    foo
  end
  return user
end
```

This would cause "method not found error" when Rails is first initialized. I can start Rails first, then add these code, then it would work (correctly aliasing and overriding the method).

How to properly do my aliasing/overriding for these `on_load` helpers?

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. Don't you say that this is possible in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17770322/1614607? Also, what do you mean by adding code after Rails is initialized?

Comment: @kardeiz I will take that answer back, when I try to answer that I forgot to restart the server. I'll provide a demo site later.